# jQuery 1.7 - binding elements that are added to the document at a later time

Tags: jquery, ajax, binding

I know I'm just confused after reading allot...

`As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

Could someone please describe how I might solve the code below.
It works as expected when the page is static. It does not work when `<!-- ajax fills this in -->`
Comments improving on my code in general are also appreciated since I'm really new to jquery.

Thanks and Merry Christmas!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('form .edit').on( {
                mouseenter: function() {
                    $(this).css({cursor:'pointer', color: 'red'});
              },
                mouseleave: function() {
                    $(this).css({cursor:'default', color: 'rgb(204, 204, 204)'});
              },
              click: function() {
                    var $t = $(this).parents('table').attr('id');
                    var $tr = '#'+ this.id;
                    var tData = $($tr +' > td'); 
                    $(tData).each(function () { 
                          var td = '#'+ this.id;
                          var $th = $(td).closest('table').find('th').eq($(td).index()).text();
                          var html = $(this).html();
                          var input = $("<input id='"+$t+$tr+this.id+"' name='"+$t+"="+$th+"'  />");
                          input.val(html);
                          $(this).html(input);
                    });             
                    $('.edit').off();
                }
            });
     });  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form id="userForm" method='get'>
<!-- ajax fills this in -->
    <table class='table' id='user'>
        <thead>
            <tr class='head'>
                <th>head 1</th>
                <th>head 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr class='edit' id='1' title='click to edit'>
                <td id='1a'>content 1a</td>
                <td id='1b'>content 1b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='edit' id='0' title='click to edit'>
                <td id='0a'>content 0a</td>
                <td id='0b'>content 0b</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
<input class='ajaxSubmitAndReturn' type='submit' value='Submit' />
<input class='ajaxCancel' type='submit' value='Cancel' />
<!-- end of ajax -->
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both good answers, thanks.@Jason Whitted and @charlietfl Follow-up question please. Can I limit the scope of `.off()` to the form that `off-ed it`? I have multiple forms and require client to submit or cancel to move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main ways to use `on()`.

One is `$(selector).on(handler)` which will work if the elements represented by the selector exist when code is fired, but does not account for future elements added to DOM.

The other is to delegate `on()` to a permanent asset in page. This can be any ancestor of the selector, or even `document`

The events get bound to the ancestor, and you add a selector argument as **target** for the event(s).

If in your case , if the form is a permanent asset you could write:

```
 /* if "form" is added by ajax, can use "document" or an ancestor of "form" that is permament in page*/
$('form').on( {
    mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).css({cursor:'pointer', color: 'red'});
      },
    mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).css({cursor:'default', color: 'rgb(204, 204, 204)'});
     },
     click: function() {/*...*/}
 }, '.edit');
```

Any class `edit` elements added to DOM in the future will be included.

In your case you are using an `events map`. Events can also be registered as space separated strings when the hanlder will be the same for multiple events, (or just to register on event) using follwing syntax:

```
 $('form').on('myCustomEvent submit', '.edit', function(){
      doSomething()
});
```

Now look at the docs, and note the optional selector, events map etc denoted by `[]` and compare to these examples and examples in docs.

Comment: great lesson here, added versatility to the suggestion of `updateStuff()` above (for me anyway). Going to accept this answer though both are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `updatestuff` concept works, and prior to introduction of delegatioon methods is the way you had to bind events to new html. The more common approach now is delegation methods I showed you

Comment: today I discovered(understand) what your saying charlietfl makes sense. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call your block of jquery code after the ajax content is loaded.

You can wrap your jQuery code in a function:

```
    function updateStuff() {
        $('form .edit').on( {
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).css({cursor:'pointer', color: 'red'});
          },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).css({cursor:'default', color: 'rgb(204, 204, 204)'});
          },
          click: function() {
                var $t = $(this).parents('table').attr('id');
                var $tr = '#'+ this.id;
                var tData = $($tr +' > td'); 
                $(tData).each(function () { 
                      var td = '#'+ this.id;
                      var $th = $(td).closest('table').find('th').eq($(td).index()).text();
                      var html = $(this).html();
                      var input = $("<input id='"+$t+$tr+this.id+"' name='"+$t+"="+$th+"'  />");
                      input.val(html);
                      $(this).html(input);
                });             
                $('.edit').off();
            }
        });
    }
```

Then after you ajax call populates the content you can simple call:

```
updateStuff();
```